# Solutions for "ERROR: lazydata failed for package..."?

Tags: r

When I try to install my GitHub package, this error occurs with lazydata. My csv files are in the "data" folder. I believe that the error may be there, but not yet what it is.

```
> install_github("igorcobelo/forestry") 
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo igorcobelo/forestry@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\RtmpYJcn76\remotes31fc114d7708\igorcobelo-forestry-64da45c/DESCRIPTION' (1.2s)
-  preparing 'forestry':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  creating default NAMESPACE file
-  building 'forestry_0.1.0.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Igor/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'forestry' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  entrada inválida na conexão de entrada 'C:\Users\Igor\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK-forestry\00new\forestry/data/data3s.csv'
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  número de itens não é múltiplo do número de colunas
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  entrada inválida na conexão de entrada 'C:\Users\Igor\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK-forestry\00new\forestry/data/data3s.csv'
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  número de itens não é múltiplo do número de colunas
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  entrada inválida na conexão de entrada 'C:\Users\Igor\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK-forestry\00new\forestry/data/data5e.csv'
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 87 did not have 6 elements
ERROR: lazydata failed for package 'forestry'
* removing 'C:/Users/Igor/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/forestry'
Erro: Failed to install 'forestry' from GitHub:
  (convertido do aviso) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Public/Documents/Wondershare/CreatorTemp/RtmpYJcn76/file31fc43283c/forestry_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have the `data` folder in the root of your repository and it is filled with csv files. You are supposed to use the `rda` format for any files in that folder. If you want to use csv files with your package, put them in `inst/extdata`.

Comment: But until a few hours ago it was working. I called csv files with "data ()". I don't know why it stopped working. I will try to change the folder as you said.

Comment: @IgorCobelo I can't comment on why it is not working now. Always used rda in `data`, and it worked fine. Use `usethis::use_data` to conveniently prepare data sets.

Comment: @IgorCobelo Problem fixed?

Comment: slava-kohut, I do not know if I would be able to clarify another doubt. I renamed my rda files in the "data" folder. However, when I import R with 'data ()', it imports from GitHub but comes with the old name. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The data set name is different? I didn't quite understand

Comment: I managed to solve it. When I saved ```save (data_bit1, file = "bit1.rda")```, the files were exported as 'bit1' but were imported as 'data_bit1'.

Comment: @IgorCobelo consider upvoting/accepting if you liked my answer. That way it will be note helpful if someone is trying to solve the same problem